# Call out to script to stop with attribute in wWWHomePage

Tags: new-operator

I'm gettinga n error message in line 8 when I try to call out the script to stop when it finds teh attribute in the Web page: field in AD.

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUserDN = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)


strwWWHomePage = objItem.Get("wWWHomePage")
If wWWHomePage  6 Then
  wscript.quit
Else
  Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
  ppt.Visible = True
  ppt.Presentations.Open "\\abngan01\tracking\ppt.pptx"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

> If wWWHomePage  6 Then

I'm assuming you want it to say:

```
 If wWWHomePage = 6 Then
```

Since the missing "=" will cause an error, but since that code really doesn't do anything anyway, other than just abort the script, you could simplify your code by only taking action if that value is not set, for example:

```
If objItem.Get("wWWHomePage") <> 6 Then
  Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
  ppt.Visible = True
  ppt.Presentations.Open "\\abngan01\tracking\ppt.pptx"
End If
```

I'm also assuming "6" is some sort of flag you've set yourself, you might want to use something a little more descriptive like "PPTSTATUS006", or something along those lines.